# How do I rewrite url to .html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url http://www.domain.com/about_us which I want to rewrite url to  http://www.domain.com/about_us.html.

I could only redirect http://www.domain.com/about_us.html to http://www.domain.com/about_us.php and it is working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$  $1.php [NC,L]
```

All the links on the page have url without html or php extension. Actual files in the server are in PHP. And I want the client should see the url has .html

Here is the .htaccess code I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$  $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: In the code you tried, you have both `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` as well as `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: pages are not redirecting from http://www.domain.com/about_us to http://www.domain.com/about_us.html. No 404 error

Comment: This is tested and working on my Apache. Make sure you don't have any  rule other than what I posted here in root .htaccess. Also when you see `http://www.domain.com/about_us` giving 404 is `http://www.domain.com/about_us.php` working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Comment: It is not working.I am getting page not found because it is redirecting to  http://www.domain.com/about_us.php.html

Comment: @BLPraveen Not sure how you're getting that, [as you can see, it works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zBuF3.png) Only difference is I have `RewriteBase /`